# Changing Jar into plugins.

Tags: jar, rcp

I've an existing rcp application and there are invoked another java application, using the jar with the java -jar option. I need to change the jar into plugin and invoke method in that. Will I be able to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which RCP platform you have. Eclipse or Netbeans? And what is your jar about? Is it a gui application?

For Netbeans you can check their Learning Trail https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/platform.html .
One of the articles is about porting a swing-based application to the platofrm https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-porting-basic.html

For Eclipse you can look to Vogella tutorials, however I haven't seen that comprehensive one on such a topic http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html .

If your jar is just a bunch of functions (at least in Netbeans) you can wrap ordinary jar into a netbeans module right in the IDE and publish some packages or register it as a service provider. In Eclipse it's IMHO better to turn it to an OSGI package.